# How to create an own map using Google Maps Engine

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-engine

I'm doing a research of Google APIs for generating it's own map. I went through some tutorials, but none of them seems to be up to date. When I try to access 
mapsengine.google.com

as they refer in the tutorials here
https://developers.google.com/maps-engine/documentation/tutorial-create-map

and here
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j6pWfoktUd8

I am redirected to some pages that seems to be a contacting site for paying customers:
https://www.google.com/work/mapsearth/

What happened to Google Maps Engine? What I am missing?

Comment: Might be wise to find a different mapping API. Google just announced that its discontinuing Google Maps Engine.

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps Engine it not free

You can try https://www.google.com/maps/d/